# Solving minimum set cover using available libraries

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to solve an instance of minimum [set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). As one possibility, is there some way of formulating the problem as a bipartite graph and using networkx?

**Update** Using dlx (dancing links) was suggested in the comments. Can anyone give a small working example of how to solve the minimum set cover problem using dlx?

Comment: How would you map your minimum set cover problem to a bipartite graph?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I was taking this from the wiki where it says "Set covering is equivalent to the hitting set problem. It is easy to see this by observing that an instance of set covering can be viewed as an arbitrary bipartite graph, with sets represented by vertices on the left, the universe represented by vertices on the right, and edges representing the inclusion of elements in sets. The task is then to find a minimum cardinality subset of left-vertices which covers all of the right-vertices."

Comment: Set cover can be mapped to any NP-complete problem on a graph, but that doesn't mean you'll be able to solve it efficiently.  Is there a reason you don't focus directly on the problem at hand (ie, set cover)?  Maybe something like: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlx

Comment: @TomSwifty That looks like a great alternative. Thank you. If you add it as an answer I will accept it in a few hours if I can work out how to install it. Could you give a minimal working example of its use please?

Answer (score 1):

Set cover can be mapped to any NP-complete problem on a graph, but that doesn't mean you'll be able to solve it efficiently. Is there a reason you don't focus directly on the problem at hand (ie, set cover)?

Maybe something like: https://pypi.org/project/dlx/

This can be installed using: pip install dlx or easy_install dlx

Comment: Thanks. I can't see a manual though. Could you give a minimal working example of dlx please?

Comment: @felix The library is all of 400 lines of code with docstrings, and includes an example in the `__main__` block.

Comment: In fact even if I could get it to work, how would you use it to solve minimum set cover?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone struggling with `DLX` library in Python, I prepared a little example

install with `pip install dlx` then do as I specified in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/marekyggdrasil/a8e63be8e34e000f2507bdb5e0755dda), it comes with couple of example instances. Enjoy!