# Find minimal set of subsets that covers a given set

Tags: python, algorithm

#### General problem

Given a set N of X unique strings: `{a1, a2, ... , aX}`
And a set M of Y subsets of N:

```
{
  m1: { ... },
  m2: { ... },
      ...
  mY: { ... },
}
```

How would you find the smallest subset of M where the union of those subsets equal N.

---

#### Example

Input form: a dictionary that maps each set in M to a list of a subset of N.

Output form: a list of the smallest subset of M.

---

Example input:

```
{
  "m1": [ "1", "4", "7" ],
  "m2": [ "1", "2" ],
  "m3": [ "2", "5", "6" ],
  "m4": [ "2", "3", "5" ],
  "m5": [ 3 ],
}
```

Example output:

```
[ "m1", "m3", "m5" ]
```

---

#### My current solution

Take the largest subset of M (first if more than one), i.e. "m1",

call this operation max(M), which should have time complexity O(Y)

Then remove m1 from M and all elements of m1 from the other subsets in M, giving us new M:

```
{
  "m2": [ "2" ],
  "m3": [ "2", "5", "6" ],
  "m4": [ "2", "3", "5" ],
  "m5": [ 3 ],
}
```

Call this operation red(M,m), which should have time complexity O(Y*X),

Then the algorithm should be

```
iterative(M):
  answer = []
  while(len(M.keys()) != 0):
    m = max(M)
    answer.append(m)
    red(M,m)
  return answer
```

Since the while loop will run maximum Y times, we get the time complexity
O(Y)+O(Y)+O(X*Y) = O(X*Y)

---

#### The Problem

I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution. Since I pick the first largest m I could switch around the order and end up with a different (and possibly suboptimal) answer.

So initially I thought "Ok, I'll just write it recursively and check them all":

max(M) will instead return a list of all m that had the most elements:
red(M,m) will return the new M

```
recursive(answer,M):
  if(len(M.keys() == 0):
    return answer
  m_list = max(M)
  for(m in m_list):
    new_answer = answer.copy()
    new_answer.append(m)
    return recursive(new_answer,red(M,m))
```

But here I realised that in the worst case max(M) would return all possible lists (if all have the same size), and red(M,m) would reduce all lists by exactly one element each run, then it would run Y*(Y-1)*...=O(Y!) times!

Comment: This is the [Set Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: THANK YOU! I was looking at this problem and thought "I KNOW this has to be a known problem!" It felt too much like a text-book problem :)

Comment: Given an input [ "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4",  "m5" ], I don't understand how is a set N defined then. Is it a union of these subsets?

Comment: @mathfux yes :)

Comment: You might like to solve this problem using Python libraries, this should help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985964/solving-minimum-set-cover-using-available-libraries

Comment: count frequency of strings in Y = O(X*Y), sort the strings by frequency = O(XlogX), give every set points by number of rare strings in it = O(Y*X), sort sets by rank = O(YlogY), add them by rank till length of new set == length of old set = O(Y), in total your at O(XY+YlogY+XlogX)- dependence on the ratio between x and y. and still i'm not sure it promises the minimum answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use actual sets to perform the operations.  For a brute force approach, a recursive function is easiest to program:

This one expects a list of sets and tries each one with a recursion on the remaining sets in the list.  It returns the shortest list of sets that it finds.

```
def setCover(setList,target=None):
    if not setList: return None
    if target  is None: target  = set.union(*setList)
    bestCover = []
    for i,values in enumerate(setList):
        remaining = target - values
        if remaining == target: continue
        if not remaining: return [values]
        subCover = setCover(setList[i+1:],remaining)
        if not subCover: continue
        if not bestCover or len(subCover)<len(bestCover)-1:
            bestCover = [values] + subCover
    return bestCover
```

output:

```
M = [
  { "1", "4", "7" },
  { "1", "2" },
  { "2", "5", "6" },
  { "2", "5" },
  { "3" },
  { "8", "6" }
]

print(setCover(M))
# [{'7', '1', '4'}, {'6', '5', '2'}, {'3'}, {'6', '8'}]
```

Brute fore is quite slow but it can be optimized.  The above function does skip sets that don't add more coverage but it performs in roughly O(n!).

There are several optimization strategies that will make it go faster.

- Sort the set list in decreasing order of set length (combined with the other optimizations)
- avoid memory allocation by not creating sub lists (i.e. pass the same list object with a starting index)
- keep track of the current best result to constrain the recursion to a maximum count (i.e. skipping over sub-solutions that have more items than the current best)
- isolate values that appear in only one set, the sets that contain them are mandatory and will always be part of the solution. Only analyse the remaining sets
- compute the maximum coverage of remaining sets for each position in the list so that you can know in advance that there will not be a solution with the remaining items

Here is an optimized version of the function:

```
from itertools import accumulate
def setCover4(setList,start=0,target=None,maxCount=None,cumSets=None):

    # short circuit recursion when imposible to cover with fewer sets than current best
    if maxCount is None: maxCount = len(setList)
    if maxCount == 0: return None

    # sort sets in descending order of their size to maximize initial coverage
    if target  is None:
        target  = set.union(*setList)
        setList = sorted(setList,key=len,reverse=True)

    # values that exist in only one set make that set mandatory in the solution
    # set them apart and combine them with the solution for the remaining sets
    if start == 0:
        singletons = target
        foundOnce  = set()
        for s in setList:
            singletons = singletons - (s & foundOnce)
            foundOnce.update(s)
        if singletons:
            mandatorySets = [ s for s in setList if s&singletons ]
            remaining     = target - set.union(*mandatorySets)
            if not remaining: return mandatorySets
            setList = [s for s in setList if not s&singletons]
            subCover = setCover4(setList,0,remaining)
            if subCover : return mandatorySets + subCover
            return None

    # predetermine the remaining coverage from each position to the end of the list
    if cumSets is None:
        cumSets = [ u for u in accumulate(reversed(setList),set.union) ][::-1]


    # try sets at each position (from start to end) recursing with remaining sets
    bestCover = []
    for i in range(start,len(setList)):
        if not cumSets[i].issuperset(target): break # no solution in remaining sets
        values = setList[i]
        remaining = target - values
        if remaining == target: continue
        if not remaining: return [values]
        subCover = setCover4(setList,i+1,remaining,maxCount-1,cumSets)
        if not subCover: continue
        if not bestCover or len(subCover)<len(bestCover)-1:
            bestCover = [values] + subCover
            maxCount  = len(bestCover)
    return bestCover
```

Performance tests show that `setCover4` responds orders of magnitude faster than the original `setCover` function

```
from timeit import timeit
import random
samples = 10

values = list(range(100))
subsetSize  = 10
subsetCount = 20
M = [ set(random.sample(values,random.randrange(1,subsetSize))) for _ in range(subsetCount) ]

t = timeit(lambda:setCover(M),number=samples)
print("setCover ",f"{t:.5f}")
t = timeit(lambda:setCover4(M),number=samples)
print("setCover4",f"{t:.5f}")

# setCover  9.11923
# setCover4 0.00095
```

More tests with varying numbers of sets and set sizes confirm the performance difference but it also shows that `setCover4`, despite being optimized, also has an exponential time pattern.

```
for subsetSize in (10,20,30):
    print("")
    for subsetCount in (10,15,18,19,20,25,30,35,40,45,50):    
        t1 = t4 = 0
        for _ in range(samples):
            M = [ set(random.sample(values,random.randrange(1,subsetSize))) for _ in range(subsetCount) ]
            if subsetCount < 25: t1 += timeit(lambda:setCover(M),number=1)
            t4 += timeit(lambda:setCover4(M),number=1)
        print(f"subsetSize={subsetSize}",f"subsetCount={subsetCount}",
              f"  setCover:{t1:8.5f}" if t1 else "  setCover: -------",
              f"  setCover4:{t4:8.5f}")
```

Results:

```
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=10   setCover: 0.01501   setCover4: 0.00039
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=15   setCover: 0.28903   setCover4: 0.00034
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=18   setCover: 2.05937   setCover4: 0.00042
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=19   setCover: 4.32700   setCover4: 0.00044
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=20   setCover: 8.08408   setCover4: 0.00045
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=25   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.00101
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=30   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.00158
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=35   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.00215
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=40   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.00813
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=45   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.01751
subsetSize=10 subsetCount=50   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.13528

subsetSize=20 subsetCount=10   setCover: 0.01878   setCover4: 0.00049
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=15   setCover: 0.35464   setCover4: 0.00050
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=18   setCover: 2.66359   setCover4: 0.00057
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=19   setCover: 4.73091   setCover4: 0.00074
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=20   setCover: 8.37055   setCover4: 0.00069
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=25   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.00176
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=30   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.00979
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=35   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.05368
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=40   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.32195
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=45   setCover: -------   setCover4: 5.34897
subsetSize=20 subsetCount=50   setCover: -------   setCover4:44.98202

subsetSize=30 subsetCount=10   setCover: 0.01798   setCover4: 0.00056
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=15   setCover: 0.32203   setCover4: 0.00058
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=18   setCover: 2.10538   setCover4: 0.00089
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=19   setCover: 4.31587   setCover4: 0.00121
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=20   setCover: 8.22864   setCover4: 0.00118
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=25   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.01261
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=30   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.05015
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=35   setCover: -------   setCover4: 0.38848
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=40   setCover: -------   setCover4: 3.29696
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=45   setCover: -------   setCover4: 8.22697
subsetSize=30 subsetCount=50   setCover: -------   setCover4:23.39054
```