# Minimal `set cover` solution in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, np, set-cover

I've been trying ways to distill (a *lot* of) database index suggestions into a set of indexes that are applicable to most databases. To do that it turns out I need to solve a pretty basic but NP complete set theory problem: the [minimum set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

This means that given a set of sets, select a subset of sets `s` that covers a certain domain `u`, but if `u` isn't given make it the union of `s`. The most optimal subset of sets is the one reaching a certain minimum, usually the minimal amount of sets, but it could also be a minimum in total weight if the sets are weighted.

```
(def s #{#{1 4 7} #{1 2} #{2 5 6} #{2 5} #{3} #{8 6}})
(def u (apply set/union s))
(set-cover s u)
=> (#{7 1 4} #{6 2 5} #{3} #{6 8})
```

I implemented a naive version of this by using `clojure.math.combinatorics`, relying on it returning subsets in order of increasing amounts of sets.

```
(defn set-cover
  ([s]
   (set-cover s (apply set/union s)))
  ([s u]
   (->> s
        (combo/subsets)
        (filter (fn [s] (= u (apply set/union s))))
        first)))
```

However this is very slow on larger `s`, because of the NP nature and the recurring unions (even optimized ones). For my use-case a version supporting weighted sets would also be preferable.

Looking into optimized versions most trails ended up in thesis-land, which I'm regrettably not smart enough for. I found this small [python implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114801/find-minimal-set-of-subsets-that-covers-a-given-set) on SO

```
def setCover(setList,target=None):
    if not setList: return None
    if target  is None: target  = set.union(*setList)
    bestCover = []
    for i,values in enumerate(setList):
        remaining = target - values
        if remaining == target: continue
        if not remaining: return [values]
        subCover = setCover(setList[i+1:],remaining)
        if not subCover: continue
        if not bestCover or len(subCover)<len(bestCover)-1:
            bestCover = [values] + subCover
    return bestCover
```

It ticks many boxes:

- work recursively
- compares partial results as optimization
- seems suitable for different minimum definitions: count or weight
- has additional optimizations I can grok

  - which can be done outside of the basic algorithm

    - sorting input sets on high minimum score (size, weight)
    - identifying unique singleton sets in `u` not found in other sets

I have been trying to translate this into Clojure as a `loop-recur` function, but couldn't get the basic version of it to work, since there are niggling paradigm gaps between the two languages.

Does anyone have suggestions how I could go about solving this problem in Clojure, either by tips how to convert the python algorithm successfully, or which other Clojure (or even Java) libraries I could use and how ?

Comment: The Python implementation looks to be following the greedy cover algorithm. There's a Java implementation of this and related algorithms [here](https://github.com/azakiio/set-cover-problem). Searching for Clojure solutions also turned up [this](https://github.com/bdesham/hitting-set)

Comment: @SteffanWestcott Yes, I've seen both. From the hitting-set/greedy-cover doc:
Uses the “greedy” algorithm (described at Wikipedia) to generate *a* set cover for the labeled hypergraph h. The set cover does not necessarily have the minimum possible cardinality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Clojure version of the greedy set cover algorithm i.e. selects a set which covers the most uncovered elements at each iteration. Rather than use `loop`/`recur` to build the complete result, it lazily returns each result element using `lazy-seq`:

```clj
(defn greedy-set-cover
  ([xs]
   (greedy-set-cover xs (apply set/union xs)))
  ([xs us]
   (lazy-seq
     (when (seq us)
       (let [x (apply max-key #(count (set/intersection us %)) xs)
             xs' (disj xs x)
             us' (set/difference us x)]
         (cons x (greedy-set-cover xs' us')))))))
```

```clj
(def s #{#{1 4 7} #{1 2} #{2 5 6} #{2 5} #{3} #{8 6}})

(greedy-set-cover s)   ;; = (#{7 1 4} #{6 2 5} #{6 8} #{3})
```

Comment: Awesome, much clearer in intent, orders faster than what I had, and easily customizable which element to pick. I directly lifted the max-key arg f into a three arity version, and had a weighted variant in 5m.

Somehow I thought it was much more complex than what it actually did due to my inability to read set notation. Nice call on the lazy-seq, didn't use that much before and it's perfect here.